# How to obtain a package on MikTeX that is only present in TeXLive?

Tags: miktex, texlive

The [`gitver`](https://ctan.org/pkg/gitver) package is currently only available on TeXLive. However, some of the collaborators in a document that I am working on which employs this package use MikTeX.

Is there a way to tell MikTeX to pick up such packages from CTAN?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows

Comment: Add an issue to the miktex issue tracker https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but I think `gitver` should now be accessible on MikTex as well as TeXLive. Does this work for you now?